# Why sprites are flipped upside-down in envMap taken by CubeCamera

Tags: three.js

I have a quick question, may be someone will explain it to me.

The scene setup is show below. I have a sprite tree, a cube and a cubeCamera. Cube material has `envMap` set to `cubeCamera.renderTarget`. (CubeCamera is places where the cube is, and also i hide the cube before calling `updateCubeMap` method).

[image: Scene setup]

So, the question is why the sprite appears upside-down in the reflection?

[image]

This seems to happen only to sprites, other objects behave as expected.

In the actual project we manually flip sprites before updating cubeCamera, and it seems to work ok. But i want to actually know why is it so? Thanks!

UPD. Demo http://webgears.ru/public/wgdemos/spriteInEnvMap/

Comment: Can you provide a simple live example to demonstrate the issue -- say, with one sprite, one object?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had a pile of work to do. Sure, I'll make a demo ASAP.

Comment: Here's the quick demo http://webgears.ru/public/wgdemos/spriteInEnvMap/

Comment: Hmmm. Please file a three.js [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). I suggest you change the controller to `OrbitControls` in the example. No need to hide cube when updating cubeMap, since it is one-sided.

Comment: I will. Thanks for help! Nice tip about not hiding the cube, i didn't think about it, you're right.